Peruvian passport with residency in the US. Doing a transfer of 6 hours in Dublin
My sister who is peruvian and holds only a peruvian passport. She lives permanently in The USA and is flying to visit me in The netherlands (where peruvians don't need a visa to enter).
She is making a stop in Dublin of 6 hours in a single ticket. She arrives at 11:45 and leaves for Amsterdam at 18:45.
Does she need a transit visa or any other type of visa? The irish immigration website is not clear and the information is contradictory.
Has anybody done similar trips?
Thank you!
